# How to preserve existing files and folders on site update?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, web-deployment

I'm using Microsoft Web Deploy to publish and update my site. (script is generated with Visual Studio). This tool removes auto-generated files and folders on update, as they are not included into install package. How to make it keep these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web Deploy command line tool has two switches that may be useful: **-skip** and **-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule**. For information on -skip, see [Web Deploy Operation Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28WS.10%29.aspx), and for DoNotDeleteRule, see [Web Deploy Rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd568992%28WS.10%29.aspx).

In Visual Studio, you may be able to tweak the deploy.cmd file to use these to achieve what you want. For more information, see [How to: Install a Deployment Package Using the deploy.cmd File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Having to edit the deploy.cmd files each time you generate them is a pain. I am using VS2017 and found I can set an environment variable on the server and deploy.cmd will use it. The deploy readme file says it:

> Alternatively, you can specify additional flags by setting the
>   "_MsDeployAdditionalFlags" environment variable. These settings are
>   used by this batch file.

So on the server I created the environment variable:

> _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule

And that did it. It now adds the rule each deploy on the server.